# how to use wp_rewrite in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problem in using `wp_rewrite`.. can't seem to make it work.. 
I need to change this URL:

```
/eduedu/wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php
```

to

```
/eduedu/generator

function create_rewrite_rules() {

  add_rewrite_rule($wordpress_root.'/generator/?$', 'wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php');
}

function flush_the_rewrite_rules () {
  flush_rewrite_rules;
}

add_action('init', 'flush_the_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'create_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: if `$wordpress_root` is defined outside of the function (which it probably is), you need to add `global $wordpress_root` before using it inside the function

Comment: Also, 'generate_rewrite_rules` is an *action*, not a *filter*. [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules)

Comment: Hi can you give me an example? I added .htaccess on the rootfolder of my wordpress and it works, but it doesnt work if the htaccess is added inside the plugins folder..

Comment: the .htaccess file needs to be in the root of your wordpress directory, not in inside directories.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function flush_the_rewrite_rules () {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

also, are you sure $wordpress_root is being initialized, you might want to debug its value to see if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi I'm new with regards in using rewrite_rules, I tried adding htaccess on root folder of my wordpress, and it works but when i place it inside the plugin folder it generates 404

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your functions.php file

```
function site_router() {

global $url_array;
    $url_array = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $route = $url_array[2];
    $template_dir = 'wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf';
    switch($route) {
    case 'generator':
        load_template($template_dir.'/samp/flash.php');
        die();
        break;
    }
}

add_action( 'send_headers', 'site_router');
```

Itll find the url domain.com/edenudu/generator and load in the template from the file you want.

No need for messing about in htaccess and no need for creating rewrite rules which are mostly used for creating pretty permalinks for existing post/pages

Comment: thank you for your reply.. I'll try this now, i'll get back to you for the result :)

Comment: After a couple of test, I get the same error
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I declare the codes you gave on the function.php of my theme folder. but still getting errors.

Comment: Hi correct me if I'm wrong, I think your codes is the same as header(Location: ''). It just redirect to other page but not fetching the output. I already tried this but still getting errors. I added ob_clean(); and it removes the TCPDF error, but it does not fetch the data. ANY ideas??